# Minecraft Crafting GUI weird bugs

Tags: gui, minecraft-modding

I'm writing a Forge mod for Minecraft 1.8. When I'm pressing the 'z' key a 3x3 Crafting grid should open. In the KeyInputHandler I call

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{
    if(KeyBindings.hackInv.isPressed())
    {
        EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer;
        World world = player.getEntityWorld();
        BlockPos pos = player.getPosition();
        player.openGui(CobaltCraft.instance, 0,world, (int) player.posX,(int) player.posY,(int) player.posZ);
    }
}
```

The code for the GuiHandler is:

```
@SubscribeEvent
public void onKeyInput(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{
    if(KeyBindings.hackInv.isPressed())
    {
        EntityPlayer player = Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer;
        World world = player.getEntityWorld();
        BlockPos pos = player.getPosition();
        player.openGui(CobaltCraft.instance, 0,world, (int) player.posX,(int) player.posY,(int) player.posZ);
    }
}
```

Ingame the Gui shows up when I press 'z'. But the Items glitch around. I have trouble picking them up (by left clicking) and sometimes the items just change places. And if I right click with the crafted item on a block it vanishes. 
Please help me I don't know what to do,
Nova